# How to use more than one fontpath in xml files?

Tags: android, xml

```
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    //.setDefaultFontPath("fonts/HelvLight-regular.ttf")
                    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.otf")
                    //.setDefaultFontPath("fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.otf")
                    //.setDefaultFontPath("fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf")
                    //.setDefaultFontPath("fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()
    );
}
```

**XML file:**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        fontPath="fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.otf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password_login"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_hint_text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/app_hint_text_color"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        fontPath="fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.otf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/app_theme_color"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
        fontPath="fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.otf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/app_theme_text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

inside the  XML I used fontpath for button,edittext and textview for this i used more than one fontpath like

**"HelveticaNeue-Light.otf"** and 
**"HelveticaNeue-Medium.otf"**

in xml file and i insert these format into CalligrapthyConfig , but the font style are not changed.

i insert helvetica font in font folder inside the assets.

can you solve my problem? how to use call CalligraphyConfig.initDefault for more than one styles and how to insert helveltical fonts...if anyone knows plz slove the issue

Comment: Do you want custom textview and custom button??

Comment: @curiousMInd yeah sir but i dont want to use any typeface or custom font.....if single xml file it will be nice but i used more than 5 xml page...then how should i used?

Comment: you need to make just a class for text view and button afterthat it will work in only single xml @Sivashankari

Comment: @curiousMind k sir i will try

Comment: You must declare the ContextWrapper for the activity. Did you do it?